Update from compileSdk 34 to 35 causes java.util.List java.util.List.reversed() to not be found at runtime
I have a library project in Kotlin compiled in Android Studio, I try to keep it up to date with latest changes whenever a small code adjustment is made.
I recently made a small adjustment and the IDE suggested updating from targetSdkVersion 34 to targetSdkVersion 35
When I do this it compiles fine but I receive runtime errors (on my tests) like this
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List java.util.List.reversed()'

This occurs because of an "offending" line at the end of this little function:
fun MutableList<Byte>.increaseDataLengthBy(numberToIncrease: Int): MutableList<Byte> {
    val dataToIncrease = this
    //The increase method adds zeros to the right so we need to reverse the data so the zeros will
    //be in the left, therefore, if the original data length is larger than 1 we need to reverse it first,
    //so the final reverse will return it to its original order.
    if (dataToIncrease.size > 1) {
        dataToIncrease.reverse()
    }

    for (i in 0 until numberToIncrease) dataToIncrease.add(0)

    return dataToIncrease.reversed().toMutableList() // <-- THIS HAS THE ERROR
}

Now in the IDE I can hover over the word "reversed" and it shows mwe a little window talking about Kotlin.collections and how this function "Returns a list with elements in reverse order" and the code seems to exist so why do I get this runtime error?
(You might ask, "why are you messing around with all this 'reverse' nonsense, just use addFirst()" and that's a good point, but it seems to only work from sdk 35 upwards and I need to be backwards compatible to at least 26)

I cannot reproduce it. Please provide an example of how the function is called that actually leads to the error.

That's gonna be due to the following issue, which I've not yet seen posted here on SO: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/350432371. The issue was posted for a bug in removeFirst(), but it pertains to several different methods, and reversed() is brought up in comment #23. I don't see any particular workarounds mentioned there, but you should just be able to handle it manually with java.util.Collections.reverse(), which is what the Kotlin extension reverse() ends up calling.

Curiously, when checking this in Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 2, it's giving me warnings and quick fix options for removeFirst() and removeLast() – "This Kotlin extension function will be hidden by java.util.SequencedCollection starting in API 35" – but not for reversed(). The available quick fixes basically just inline the extensions, though, so if there was one for reversed(), it would likely use the java.util.Collections method.

thanks @MikeM. If you want proper credit please post this as an answer!

I'm good. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

You don’t need to use the new addFirst method, you can just use add(0, 0); which exists since Java 2 (in other words, since the introduction of the Collection API). But when you have to insert more than one value, it’s potentially more efficient to use addAll(0, Collections.nCopies( numberToIncrease, 0));

Thanks @Holger I tried this but for some reason it adds two bytes instead of one. I can't understand why it acts differently from the regular add but I'm going with @mike-m 's suggestion for now

@Kibi I guess, Kotlin “helpfully” augmented the API with an add method that can add more than value, because, well, never would a method like add(oneElement, anotherElement) clash with an add(index, element)…

Many thanks to @MikeM. for suggestions (if you want to post an answer I will accept it)
I changed the code to say explicitly
java.util.Collections.reverse(dataToIncrease)
return dataToIncrease.toMutableList()

...and that compiles and runs fine under sdk 35!
The IDE suggested changing the static call with the kotlin stdlib so now I have
dataToIncrease.reverse()
return dataToIncrease.toMutableList()

I looked up what the difference between "reverse and "reversed" is and it seems reversed always returns a read-only result....since I don't ever write to the results I get from this function - I instead copy them, it seems that this code will work well for me.
Thanks for your help!
